# Can one make shortcuts (launchers) to Settings actions?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, settings, home-screen-shortcuts

I have a Samsung tablet with Kitkat and I'd like to be able to access some of the setting fast. For example I'd like to unmount the SD card or change the screen lock from "None" to "Password" using a shortcut or launcher on the desktop. Is this possible without 3rd party apps? Right now I have to dig through the settings to do these tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible without third party apps. At least not on stock Android. But you could check out [Secure Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin). It provides access to a lot of settings.

Comment: "*I think it is not possible without third party apps.*" -- why so?

Comment: @Firelord Because I do not know of a way to do this with android itself. As far as I know you always need a third party app/widget.